# How to deal with errors in polychoric-to-sem work in Stata commands?

Tags: stata

I am doing polychoric-to-sem work. I get error messages from my code.

When I execute these commands

```
forvalues i=1/`: word count `thevars' ' {
forvalues j=1/`i' {
local setcor `setcor' `=polychR[`i',`j']'
 }
if `i' < `: word count `thevars' ' local setcor `setcor' \
 }
local N = _N
```

error messages from Stata are

```
program error:  matching close brace not found
program error:  matching close brace not found
```

Next to this I tried `ssd` command as in

```
ssd init `thevars', clear
```

The error message is:

```
no; data in memory would be lost
```

I tried it even after saving the existing data but error message still comes with no results.

Where I am going wrong in these two steps?

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with this posting, as you don't explain what you are trying to do 
or what is in the local macro or matrix you are using.

The line

```
 if `i' < `: word count `thevars' ' local setcor `setcor' \
```

looks pointless as well as illegal. The backslash is illegal and is probably causing the next brace } to be ignored. Without the backslash, the line makes sense, but it is pointless. It is best that you tell us what you want to do.  At a guess, you are copying code from somewhere rather than writing it yourself, so please give an exact copy of the original together with an explanation of your goal.

Comment: I have to rum sem on data set consisting of both continuous and categorical observed variables.In statalist archive it was mentioned to use polychoric matrix and then perform sem. I copied this coding from there. I have just tried to execute command after removing backslash but "invalid syntax" message appears.

Comment: Just want to do sem after polychoric matrix estimation

Comment: Yes, that is statistical context which I can guess, but it gives zero information on what your code is aimed at doing.

Comment: If you can't give a better explanation of what your code is trying to do, your question remains impossible to answer fully. The Statalist  archive contains tens of thousands of messages; do you really think that's an adequate reference?

Comment: Can someone tell me what commands to use for sem using correlation matrices?

Comment: Perhaps StasK will help, since the code is originally his: http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2012-08/msg01403.html